# Image to Integer

Tags: android

How to convert image resources to integer?
I used this:

```
int rh=this.getResources().getIdentifier("ic_launcher", null, this.getPackageName());
```

but it wont work.
I logcat this and the value of rh is 0 always.
is there any alternative way to convert image to integer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this specifing type:

```
int rh=this.getResources().getIdentifier("ic_launcher", "drawable", this.getPackageName());
```

Keep in mind it IS NOT converting image to integer, `getIdentifier()` merely finds resource id which is used to find resource packed in .apk file.

Comment: thanks man. thats the answer. i forgot the "drawable" argument.

Answer (score 2):

Your this:

```
int i = this.getResources().getIdentifier("ic_launcher", "strings", this.getPackageName());
```

or

```
int i = this.getResources().getIdentifier("ic_launcher", "drawable", this.getPackageName());
```

1 of those should be working.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this without using resource also.

```
int id=R.drawable.icon;
```

Here, `icon` is image in your drawable folder.

To set this `id` value to integer

```
ImageView imageView=null;
imageView.setImageResource(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("ic_launcher","drawable", getPackageName());
```

and it will return you resource id which is integer.

Answer (score 0):

If all else doesn't work try this piece of code:

```
public static int getResId(String variableName, Class<?> c) {
Field field = null;
int resId = 0;
try {
    field = c.getField(variableName);
    try {
        resId = field.getInt(null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return resId;
```

}

n your case:

```
int x = getResId("ic_launcher", R.drawable-???.class);
```

where ??? is the correct drawable folder.